# How to get response data from ConnectionRequest when response code is an error code

Tags: java, http, codenameone

I've got a `ConnectionRequest` that is failing when I try to access a webservice with a 401 response code.

From the server docs it seems that when a 401 response is returned an error message is still sent thru HTTP but the `readResponse` method isn't invoked so I can't read that error.

Is there another method or API to read the error stream from a response, e.g. in JavaSE there is a specific error stream but I could find no such stream in Codename One.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ConnectionRequest` by default will ignore the response data if the error code is not 200, in order to get the data you need to invoke `setReadResponseForErrors(true)` on the ConnectionRequest object.

Your standard `readResponse` will be invoked with the error stream when such an error is returned.